# what is the VBA for the USING statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, using-statement, using-directives

In csharp or vb.net we use the `using` statement for reasons that we know: One can open the database and close it automatically without writing it explicitly. 
I would like to do the samething in `VBA`

1. how to do it?
2. Are all VB.NET statement/keywords/ available in VBA ?
3. how to tell if a given statement is(was) known in VBA ? Is it there a library(glosary) of all VBA statements/keyword/operators ?

c#

```
  using(var db=new MyDbContext()){
   //do work here
  }
```

vb.net

```
    Using s = New MyDbContext()
     '--..do work here
    End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering just your first question, as you've hinted, `Using` is just syntactic sugar for calling `Dispose()` on an object instance which implements the `IDisposable` interface.

It is equivalent to

```
Dim s as MyDbContext
Try
   s = New MyDbContext()
   // ...
Finally
   s.Dispose()
End Try
```

Since `VBA` doesn't support the `Using` sugar, and in the absence of structured `Try..Catch` exception handling, you'll need to explicitly call `Dispose()` on all paths which control the lifespan of the object (`MyDbContext` in your case). In which case you may as well have just used `.Close()`

Comment: Since `Dispose()` generally will just call `Close()` for most of the Db resources, there isn't really to choose between `Close()` and `Dispose()`

Comment: You can simulate a TRY CATCH block in VBA Please see here 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/30991653/4413676

Answer (score 1):

There is no VBA equivalent to the `Using` statement.

The [VBA developer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ff688774.aspx) provides samples and even downloadable offline versions of the VBA documentation.